# Unresolved reference 'cx_freeze' in python

Tags: python, cx-freeze

[my error - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVjh2.png)

Hey guys, I get the error

> Unresolved reference 'cx_freeze'

on the project file. I download the package by typing:

```
pip install cx_freeze
```

on the terminal.

This is my full `setup.py` file:

```
import sys
import os
import files as files
from cx_freeze import setup, Executable

files = ['icon.png']

target = Executable(
    script="gui/gui.py",
    base="Win32GUI",
    icon="icon.png"
)

setup(
    name="PythonGUI",
    version="1.0",
    description="Modern GUI",
    author="Idan Noyshul",
    options={"build_exe": {'include_files': files}},
    executables=[target]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `cx_freeze` with `cx_Freeze`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
```

Comment: hi thanks, but I found out the problem. I open my interpreter and download the package from there.